# Responsive flexbox layout wrap issue

Tags: css, flexbox

I have these two different layouts illustrated in the code below. My issue is that I can't replicate these layouts without changing the markup. I was wondering if there was some fancy flexbox way I can accomplish exactly this while only using one html scheme. Note: the container will need to have a dynamic height. The solution doesn't necessarily have to use flexbox as long as the desired layout is achieved.

```css
main {
  width: 750px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}



.a {
  background: red;
  width: 40%;
}
.b {
  background: blue;
  width: 60%;
}
.c {
  background: green;
}


.a-mobile {
  background: red;
  width: 40%;
}
.b-mobile {
  background: blue;
  width: 60%;
}
.c-mobile {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Desktop</h2>
<main>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b
   <div class="c">c</div>
  </div>
</main>

<h2>Mobile</h2>
<main>
  <div class="a-mobile">a-mobile</div>
  <div class="b-mobile">b-mobile</div>
  <div class="c-mobile">c-mobile</div>
</main>
```

Comment: The answer is yes, if you can set a height on the container. Is that an option here?

Comment: With floats & flexbox, this is possible without need of height.

Comment: @Michael_B Going to need a dynamic height on the container unfortunately.

Comment: Then a pure flex solution is not currently possible without altering the mark-up.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu that's good news, can you show me an example?

Comment: what is the problem with changing the markup?

Comment: @ptts I want it to be responsive and clean. If I move the markup around while the window resizes I'd need to use JS which is a little convoluted for something like this I think. I could use duplicate markup as a last resort but there are cases where there is quite a bit of text inside some of these elements where I don't necessarily want all the extra stuff being sent to the client if it can at all be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the `float`-`flexbox` method I described in the comments. Not particularly fond of it, but it does exactly what you asked for.

It's *hacky* and, from my POV, goes in the same category as Bootstrap 3's `.clearfix::before|after` *hack* — `{display:table; content: " ";}` — it is a practical solution to a real layout problem, usable until a better, cleaner one will have better browser support and render this one obsolete.

```css
main {
  width: 750px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  color: white;
}
.a {
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 40%;
}
.b {
  background: blue;
  flex-basis: 60%;
}
.c {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  main {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .a {
    float: left;
    min-width: 40%;
  }
  .b,.c {
    padding-left: 40%;
  }
  .a,.c {
    padding-bottom: 32768px;
    margin-bottom: -32768px;
    }
}
```

```html
<main>
<div class="a">a<br />a<br />a<br/>a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</main>
<main>
<div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b<br />b<br />b<br/>b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
</main>
<main>
<div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c<br />c<br />c<br/>c</div>
</main>
```

Comment: This is awesome! A little hacky yes, but not nearly half as bad as I was expecting. Thanks for the write up.

Answer (score 2):

`display:grid` will be useful for this kind of layout:

but this <del>is still experimental and</del>(2020) can be tested in [few browsers](http://gridbyexample.com/browsers/), see also http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

A tutorial among others https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% auto;
}
.a {
  background: red;
  grid-row-end: span 2
}
.b,
.c {
  background: green;
}
.c {
  background: lightblue
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {/* value setted for the demo */
  .a {
    grid-row-end: span 1/* reset optionnal in this very case */
  }
  .c {
    grid-column-end: span 2
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="a"> break point set at 700px for demo</div>
  <div class="b"> i don't move much myself :)</div>
  <div class="c"> see in full page to see me aside the red box and below the green one</div>
</main>
```

[**codepen to play with**](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rjmQMo)

Comment: CSS grid is awesome but with my current project I can't touch it until it's more well supported. One day...

Comment: @anthony-dandrea unfortunately, with flex or else method , you will need to set an height for the colum layout :(   float example http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZLKmLm i believe someone else will come up with the flex approach + height.. Note that javascript can help you to sort out height needed to be set on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, it's independent of flex box, and does not need fixed height.
Flexbox does not do a good job of adjusting to two dimensional layouts!

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  width: 750px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 100%;
}

.a {
  background: red;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.b {
  background: blue;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.c {
  background: green;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
   .a {
    width: 40%;
     height: 50%;
  }

  .c {
    width: 100%;
  } 
}
```

```html
<h2>Desktop and Mobile</h2>
<main>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
   <div class="c">c</div>
</main>
```

Comment: It appears this does rely on a set height. This example adjusts to the height of the body which is 100%. Without it, it breaks.

Comment: Ah... you are right... I did not think about it that way.  I will try it out and see if I can come up with a better solution!